# Table of Contents formatting issue

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, formatting

I am quite new to LaTeX and am trying to write my own notes using it, but I am having some issues with formatting.

Shown below is a minimal working example of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left = 2.54 cm, right = 2.54 cm, top = 2.54 cm, bottom = 2.54 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\setlength{\tabcolsep}{24 pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Discrete Uniform Distribution \\}

\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l l}
Abbreviation & DiscUnif$(n)$ \\
Type & Discrete \\
Rationale & Equally likely outcomes \\
Sample Space & $[1, n]\ \forall\ n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ \\
Probability Mass Function & $f(x) = \frac 1 n\ \forall\ x \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Moments} & $E(X) = \frac {n + 1} 2$ \\
& $Var(X) = \frac {n^2 - 1} {12}$ \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

However, my Table of Contents comes out like this:

[image: Table of Contents Formatting Error]

As can be seen in the image above, my "Discrete Uniform Distribution" section does indeed start on page 2, but I would like the page number to be on the same line as the name of the corresponding section. The other sections that I have in my document which follow all have the same page numbering issue i.e. the related page number for the section appears on the next line.

What is the problem with my code here?

Also, as mentioned, I am very new to LaTeX (only been using it for about a week), so if I have any "bad coding", please feel free to suggest how I may improve :)

Comment: you are forcing a line break with `\\ ` which should never appear at the end of any paragraph and certainly not in a section heading.

Comment: please always post examples in a form that people can run them and see the issue. You have removed `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` here which forces people to notice that and guess where you intend them to be put back.

Comment: the spacing after section headings is a document level setting you could copy the line from article.cls and increase it or use a package such as secsty that lets you adjust several parameters for headings

Comment: `\\ ` does not add any vertical space it is forcing your heading to be a two-line paragraph (and presumably generating a warning that the line is empty, underful)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Apologies for not indicating where my document begins and ends. I have edited my post! Also, why do you say that \\ does not add any vertical space? I mean, it adds an empty line, which is technically vertical space right?

Comment: no it is completely different to vertical space: it is a line of _text_ that is empty, so it is not dropped at a page break, it messes up the rules for allowing or not allowing page breaks after the first line of a paragraph, basically in all respects `\\ ` at end of a paragraph works the same way as if you had `\\ zzz` at the end of the paragraph, with an extra final line of the paragraph with an invisible zzz.  Tex warns you about badness  10000 which is it's _maximum_ assesment for how bad the output is. Dom't ignore that warning.

Comment: hmm see what I mean about guessing where `\begin{document}` should go..  `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \tableofcontents
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always wrong to have `\\` at the end of a paragraph (and forcing a line break at the send of a section heading is particularly weird, as you see from your output)

TeX does warn about both the table of contents and the main heading

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 1--1
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 19--19
```

note 10000 is the maximum badness.

as you have double spaced the table, the spacing above may look a little tight so you could correct with `\bigskip` for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left = 2.54 cm, right = 2.54 cm, top = 2.54 cm, bottom = 2.54 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\setlength{\tabcolsep}{24 pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Discrete Uniform Distribution}

\begin{flushleft}
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}l l}
Abbreviation & DiscUnif$(n)$ \\
Type & Discrete \\
Rationale & Equally likely outcomes \\
Sample Space & $[1, n]\ \forall\ n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ \\
Probability Mass Function & $f(x) = \frac 1 n\ \forall\ x \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Moments} & $E(X) = \frac {n + 1} 2$ \\
& $Var(X) = \frac {n^2 - 1} {12}$ \\
\end{tabular}  
\end{flushleft}


\end{document}
```

---

If you want to ajust the spacing after all sections not just this one, you can copy the lines from article

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%<<<
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

and adjust the value from 3.5ex to whatever size you want eg 12pt for the default baseline for the 10pt font. (negate the values to suppress indentation)

Normally do this in teh preamble but here I do it mid document to show the difference, and making it 24pt (twice baseline) to be more visible as there is not much difference between 2.3ex and one baselineskip.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Discrete Uniform Distribution}

text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 

\section{Something else}

text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {24pt \@plus 2pt}% {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother




\section{Discrete Uniform Distribution}

text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 

\section{Something else}

text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for putting your comments into an answer! I have two questions. Firstly, what is the point of using begin{flushleft} and end{flushleft}? I tried it and noticed it made no difference to the output. Secondly, I noticed you added an @{} after begin{tabular}. Why is this needed and what does it do?

Comment: @EthanMark  flushleft (or center or whatever) is good style around non-loating tables as adjusts the vertical spacing, here actually unseen as it only affects the space below as the space above controlled by the heading. `@{}` removes the tabcolsep from the left so it is not indented . I also added some notes about general section head spacing

Comment: the plus and minus components of a TeX dimen are how much the space can stretch and shrink (what the latex book calls a rubber length, or texbook calls glue) @EthanMark

Comment: @EthanMark I marked the wrong argument, that's the space before, hang on...

Comment: @EthanMark done

Comment: I see. Thank you for taking the time to write all of that! So in essence, the -3.5ex portion controls the spacing before section headers, while the 2.3ex portion controls the spacing after?

Comment: @EthanMark yes and the signs are used as boolean flags for display-or-runin  and indent-or-dont-indent respectively.

Comment: Alright! And one last thing, for a default article in 10pt font size, you were saying that 1 line spacing is 12pt, is that correct?

Comment: @EthanMark yes you can look in size10.clo or simply use `\showthe\baselineskip` to see the value although actually that is the line spacing at 10pt you may have meant the line spacing of the section heading font which is `\Large` so 18pt

Comment: paragraphs are ended by a blank line in the source @EthanMark (if you want vertical space there use `parskip` package this is a faq)

Comment: What does it mean to "leave a blank line"? For example, if I type "This is A.", then I press enter twice (to "leave a blank line"), then I type "This is B.", the two sentences do not actually have any spacing between each other.

Comment: sorry this is going on too long. The traditional way to show end of paragraph in a typeset document is to have no additional vertical space but to indent the start of the new paragraph. That is the latex default. If you want vertical space and no indentation between paragraphs (as in this site) use `\usepackage{parskip}` as I said. The markup of paragraphs does not change, just leave a blank line in the source in either case. If you have more questions ask a new question (but these are all duplicates with answers on site) @EthanMark

Comment: Alright! Thanks for all your help and sorry for taking up so much of your time :)